# Backbone.Marionette + Rails app redirects after form submission. Why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, backbone.js, marionette

I have a sample app that I'm working on that uses Ruby on Rails for the server backend and Backbone.Marionette for the client-side. The main functionality is a form to "order a widget". I'm using [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) to create the form. The oddity that is throwing things off is that once I submit the form and save the model to the Rails backend, the browser is automatically redirected to the root url with all of the form params as URL params (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/?quantity=4&color=red&needed_by=2015-06-15T04%3A00%3A00.000Z&kind=Widget+Pro`). This redirection prompts Rails to GET the `#index` method on the controller (which is the blank form, as this is the sole function of the app).

For the life of me, I can't find what is causing this. I don't know if its Backbone, Marionette, or backbone-forms. I won't to either stop it or at least understand it well enough to get it do what I want.

If it helps, here's the code that generates the form, waits for submission, commits the Backbone.Model, then saves it to the Rails backend:

```
@WidgetApp.module "Widget.Create", (Create, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  # VIEW
  class Create.Widget extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "create_widget"

  # Controller
  class Create.Controller extends Marionette.Controller

    initialize: ->
      widget = App.request "new:widget:entity"

      # newView = new Create.Widget
      # App.mainRegion.show newView
      form = new Backbone.Form(
        template: _.template($('#formTemplate').html())
        model: widget
        )
      App.mainRegion.show(form.render())
      # Run validation before submitting
      form.on 'submit', (event) ->
        errs = form.commit({ validate: true })
        if errs
          console.log errs
          event.preventDefault()
        widget.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the statement `event.preventDefault()` as your first statement in the event listener of form submit.I was having the same problem adding the same statement in the first line of the event listener solved my problem.

Comment: This actually got me to the solution, so thank you a ton for that, but I'm still a bit confused as to why this solves the problem. What is the "default" that this function "prevents"? What is the `event` object? Is this a `backbone-forms` specific issue, or more general? I just want to better understand **why** this works.

Comment: @smargh Actually browser append all the form data to the url and redirects to it if no form method is defined in the form tag of html assuming that default method is GET method.So event.preventDefault() prevents this default behaviour.